# Using accept.js with Authorize.net AIM

Tags: jquery, authorize.net, oscommerce

We currently use Oscommerce with Authorize.net AIM enabled. We are trying to integrate accept.js.

Problem: 
1. When authorize.net AIM module is enabled the form does not post to confirmation page and produces error

2. When AIM module is disabled then the form gets posted to confirmation page but we get "Select payment method"

We understand that atleast 1 payment method has to be enabled.

QUESTION: 
1. is there are possibility of integrating accept.js with AIM?  How?
2. If AIM is disabled then how to post to confirmation page in oscommerce?

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Authorize.Net AIM does not support the payment nonce or one-time token generated by Accept.js. Instead you will need to use the [Authorize.Net API](https://developer.authorize.net/api/reference) using either XML or JSON.

Comment: I am new to oscommerce can you please provide any sample code for implementing authorize.net API in php (oscommerce). Because i dont undrstand where and how to use it. "when i disabled authorize.net AIM" it takes me to cash on delivery. I dont know how to use API and accept.js in oscommerce.